# Glide prefetch vs Recyclerview Prefetch for Images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

Actually I'm a beginner in android so please do excuse me if my question is foolish . I just have learned `glide prefetch` but then I also heard a topic `recyclerview prefetch` . So, I want to know if my recyclerview is showing images then which one would be better option to prefetch images.

*Please help me to get out of this confusion.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView prefetch will just create/bind the views ahead of time ([see here for more information](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setInitialPrefetchItemCount%28int%29) and [here for something more detailed](https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710)). So if you happen to have a user who scrolls fast, you will still see pictures taking some time to load the first time (to download the picture before Glide has done any caching)

Glide preload on the other hand can be called anytime to download the images ahead of time ([more information here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/430/com/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder.html#preload-int-int-)). As soon as you get the URL of the image you want to display, you can cache it (download it) so it will be ready to be displayed later.

To have something as smooth as possible you could use a combination of the 2 (the Glide preload would download the images when you get new data and the RecyclerView prefetch would draw the view before it's needed).

Just make sure to check both documentations and keep in mind that you do extra work (download and pre-draw/bind) that may not be needed (you can probably measure the impact on low end devices to make sure it's not too much work).